# Is there a generic way to create an URL template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm looking for an easy way to compose URLs in the frontend with JavaScript. Let's take the URL patterns from the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views) as an example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

I'd like to create a template from an URL name reference (I'm using MustacheJS in the example, but I'm not fixed on any particular syntax):

```
assert get_url_template('detail') == "/polls/{{ question_id }}/"
assert get_url_template('results') == "/polls/{{ question_id }}/results/"
```

In the frontend, I would simple supply `question_id` and get a complete URL. Of course, this has to work for most if not all URL patterns.

Is there any easy way to do this or do I have to hack something together based on Django's `urlresolver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to hack something simple which does what I wanted, maybe it'll be useful for someone. It's a template tag which replaces named groups with `{{ name }}` sequences and takes the URL name as a single parameter.

```py
import re

from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver, get_urlconf   

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def data_url(urlname):

    urlconf = get_urlconf()
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)

    if urlname not in resolver.reverse_dict:
        return ""

    url = resolver.reverse_dict[urlname][0][-1][0]
    url = re.sub(r'%\((.*?)\)s', '{{ \g<1> }}', url)

    return "/%s" % url
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of JS libraries which will do this. A quick google showed up [django-js-reverse](https://github.com/version2/django-js-reverse) which looks quite nice, but has some open issues which are worth a look. You could always fork and fix, or at the least see how they do it.

[EDIT] Alternatively, if you want to avoid the ajax route, you could write a Django inclusion tag which (somehow - TBC) imports the urlconf and renders a template which lays out the url syntax for each in a JS data structure, wrapped in a  block, so that they're all loaded into the template and available. It's not a particularly pretty solution, though...

Comment: I used to have an implementation of something like this myself, however, this is essentially AJAXified URL resolving. While this solves the need, it introduces more requests and couples my frontend to the backend even more -- I prefer to have the backend tell the frontend "Work with these URLs", not have the frontend find them. Ironically, my frontend still needs to know the exact URL of the resolving endpoint which is what I explicitely want to avoid too.

Comment: Fair enough - I agree it'd be nicer to it without an AJAX call. That said, the coupling between front end and back end is explicit anyway if you want to resolve backend URLs via frontend code...

Comment: That's the point: I don't want to fully resolve them, I want the frontend to work with the URLs the backend gives it and optionally replace some variables in them, i.e. user has clicked on a button with ID 10, I want the 10 to replace the previous ID in the URL (via HTML5 history), so the frontend actually only needs a template with a placeholder -- and for that the backend needs to somehow half-resolve the URLs, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah. One ugly solution i've used in the past is to resolve the URL with a fake param - eg : $(document).data("{% url 'foo_bar' 0 %}"); then grab that in JS and regex-replace the 0 value.